# Pytorch Image Segmentation Problems BCELoss

Tags: python, pytorch

Currently I am creating an Unet in order to do Image Segmentation.
In my Unet, the last output channel is 183 which is the classes size.
When I was doing the train, It shows the following error.
I tried the BCEWithLogitsLoss function which works for me, but it does not shows me the right output images and it slowly train to a black image, instead of GrayScale Classes Image.
[Expected image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zsh1S.png)[OutPut Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OSYQ.png)

```py
    def Append_files():

        train_folder = "train/"

        train_label_folder = "train_label/"

        root_dir = "data/Train_Data/"

        ext_cond = lambda filename:filename.endswith('.png')
        train_data = os.path.join(root_dir,train_folder)
        train_data_path = lambda filename: True
        train_data_label = os.path.join(root_dir,train_label_folder)
        train_data_label_path = lambda filename: True
        filtered_train_data = []
        filtered_train_label_data = []

        for path, _, files in os.walk(train_data):
              files.sort()
              for file in files:
                  if train_data_path(file) and ext_cond(file):
                        full_file_path = os.path.join(path,file)
                        filtered_train_data.append(full_file_path)

        for path,_,files in os.walk(train_data_label):
              files.sort()
              for file in files:
                    if train_data_label_path(file) and ext_cond(file):
                            full_file_path = os.path.join(path,file)
                            filtered_train_label_data.append(full_file_path)
    return filtered_train_data, filtered_train_label_data

def open_image(train_data,train_data_label):

    data = Image.open(train_data)
    data = np.array(data)
    label = Image.open(train_data_label)
    label = np.array(label)

    return data,label

def load_dataset(train_data,train_label_data):

    train_set_loader = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToPILImage(),transforms.CenterCrop(size=(572,572)),transforms.ToTensor()])
    train_label_set_loader = transforms.Compose([transforms.ToPILImage(),transforms.CenterCrop(size=(388,388)),transforms.ToTensor()])

    train_set = train_set_loader(train_data)
    train_label_set = train_label_set_loader(train_label_data)

    return train_set, train_label_set



### Main
if __name__ == '__main__':

    epochs = 100
    loss = 0
    train_data,train_label_data = Append_files()
    data_len = len(train_data)

    model = UNet(3,183).to(device)

    #loss_func = nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss()
    loss_func = nn.BCELoss()
    get_optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(),0.001,betas=(0.9,0.999),eps=0.1,weight_decay = 0,amsgrad=False)

    for epoch in range(epochs):
        print ('starting epoch{}/{}.'.format(epoch+1,epochs))
        for i in range(data_len):

            data, label = open_image(train_data[i],train_label_data[i])

            train, label = load_dataset(data,label)

            train = Variable(train).to(device)
            label = Variable(label).to(device)


            train = train.unsqueeze(0)
            label = label.unsqueeze(0)

            get_optimizer.zero_grad()                #train.shape = 1,1,388,388
            train_real_image = model.forward(train)  #train_real_image.shape = 1,1,388,388  
                                                     #I can change it to 1,183,388 where 183 is the class size


        #Loss Function
            #Label.shape = 1,1,388,388
            loss = loss_func(train_real_image,label)
            print (loss)
            loss.backward()
            get_optimizer.step()
```

```
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1556653183467/work/aten/src/THCUNN/BCECriterion.cu:42: Acctype bce_functor<Dtype, Acctype>::operator()(Tuple) [with Tuple = thrust::detail::tuple_of_iterator_references<thrust::device_reference<float>, thrust::device_reference<float>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>, Dtype = float, Acctype = float]: block: [23,0,0], thread: [28,0,0] Assertion `input >= 0. && input <= 1.` failed.
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1556653183467/work/aten/src/THCUNN/BCECriterion.cu:42: Acctype bce_functor<Dtype, Acctype>::operator()(Tuple) [with Tuple = thrust::detail::tuple_of_iterator_references<thrust::device_reference<float>, thrust::device_reference<float>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>, Dtype = float, Acctype = float]: block: [23,0,0], thread: [29,0,0] Assertion `input >= 0. && input <= 1.` failed.
/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1556653183467/work/aten/src/THCUNN/BCECriterion.cu:42: Acctype bce_functor<Dtype, Acctype>::operator()(Tuple) [with Tuple = thrust::detail::tuple_of_iterator_references<thrust::device_reference<float>, thrust::device_reference<float>, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type, thrust::null_type>, Dtype = float, Acctype = float]: block: [23,0,0], thread: [31,0,0] Assertion `input >= 0. && input <= 1.` failed.

RuntimeError: reduce failed to synchronize: device-side assert triggered
```

Answer (score 0):

`nn.BCELoss` expects that we have already applied sigmoid activation over logits, while `nn.BCEWithLogitsLoss` expects logits as inputs and internally applies sigmoid activation over logits before calculating binary cross entropy loss. You can have a look at this [discussion](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/bceloss-vs-bcewithlogitsloss/33586/4).

So, if you want to go with `nn.BCELoss` make sure you apply activation function to logits before sending them to `loss_func`.

Comment: Thank you for helping; however, it is still remind the same problems as I showed on my Expected Image and Output Image. I am wondering that what should be the tensor shape looks like in both training images and label images.

Comment: My Label image tensor is [1,1,388,388], and how can i convert to [1,183,388,388] which is  Batch,Classes,H,W

Comment: @TimmyKwok instead of doing  this, which is space-expensive, I would suggest to use [`nn.NLLLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.NLLLoss).

Comment: Not Working as Well. I used it